# OpenCV to find specific co-ordinates in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm working on an iOS app with OpenCV. I am trying to locate the position of the box around the person. I would like to start by getting the width of the box.

I'm converting the image to Greyscale and then using a Canny edge detector.

Link to image here http://s18.postimg.org/bbpczub2x/sampleshot.png

What would be the best way to get the coordinates of the extreme horizontal ends of the box (marked by the red in the picture)? Any pre-existing functions?

Comment: are you not using cvRect? Can you use http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#cvsize

Comment: The box is pre-drawn, that is to say before any processing is done.

Comment: Then edge detection for the box may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm going to go ahead and answer this myself. After a bit of digging, I found the Hough Line Transform which perfectly suits my needs.

It is pretty well documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).

I wanted higher accuracy, so I used HoughLinesP.

```
    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 100, 10);
```

The arguments are well defined and its pretty much trial and error after that to perfect it. I've used a Median Blur and a Canny Edge Detector before this for better results.